# Use Keywords in variable section- Robot framework

Tags: robotframework

i am trying to create a variable in the variables section but by appreciating it i am doing something wrong.

so I have it now and it works.

```
*** Variables ***


*** Test Cases ***
MyTest
    ${DATA}=     read_csv_file     ../data.csv
    Log     ${DATA}
```

read_csv_file is a keyword that i design.

I would like it to work like this.
but the log only shows "read_csv_file ../data.csv"

```
*** Variables ***
${DATA}=     read_csv_file     ../data.csv

*** Test Cases ***
MyTest
    Log     ${DATA}
```

Comment: No, that's not supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Variables section does not allow to execute keywords, only to define variables, eventually using other variables.

To do what you want, you need to add a Variables python file import, where you can pass an argument to it. For example:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SomeLibrary.py
Variables         variables_from_csv_file.py    ../data.csv
```

Your `variables_from_csv_file.py` file would then call your reader and define the ${DATA} variable, like for example:

```
from mylib import read_csv_file

def get_variables(args):
        data = { "DATA": read_csv_file(args) }
        return data
```

See [Variable files](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#id651)

Comment: Sorry about the delay in responding. I understand the idea, but now how can I access the variable. if you wanted to make a Log of the read data, just put "Log  ${DATA}" or do you have to define the variable? that part is not clear to me

Comment: I hope you have tried by now, `Log     ${DATA}` or `Log Many    ${DATA}`.